Как избежать конфликта данных MySQL при запросах от нескольких клиентов одновременно
Допустим у нас есть SQL таблица users, которая содержит строки id и respect. Есть скрипт обработчик на php который по запросу от клиента добавляет или понижает значение respect, причем если значение respect больше 100, то повышает или понижает на 10, а если меньше, то на 5.
Пример на php будет выглядеть так
/*1*/$id = $_POST['id'];
/*2*/$type = $_POST['type'];
/*3*/$user = R::findOne('users', 'id = ?', array($id));//Запрос к БД за данных о /*1*/пользователе
/*4*/$current_respect = $user->respect;
/*5*/$rate = 5;
/*6*/if($current_respect > 100){
/*7*/    $rate = 10;
/*8*/}
/*9*/if($_POST['type'] == 'increase'){
/*10*/    $user->respect += rate;
/*11*/}elseif($_POST['type'] == 'decrease'){
/*12*/    $user->respect -= rate;
/*13*/}
/*14*/R::store($user);

При достаточно большом количестве запросов от разных пользователей может случиться так, что после проверки величины respect, но до сохранения его нового значения, другая копия скрипта при обработке другого запроса также проверит старое значение и изменять будет его, в результате чего на выходе мы получим два разных значения, которые не учитывали изменения друг друга?
Например:

В данный момент времени у user с id = 1 значение respect равно 101
Почти одновременно делается два запроса разными клиентами. Сначала:

"{id:1,type:increase}" //Уменьшить респект пользователю id=1

Затем:
"{id:1,type:increase}" //Увеличить респект пользователю id=1


Допустим есть две копии скрипта обработчика, которые обрабатывают два этих запроса соответственно. Будем называть их script1 и script2
Из-за того, что запросы отправлялись почти одновременно, данные ниже действия выполнялись в следующей последовательности:

4.1 Выполняется строка 6 script1, в которой идет проверка respect пользователя и равна она 101
4.2 Выполняется строка 6 script2, в которой идет проверка respect пользователя и равна она все ещё 101, так как строка 14 script1 еще не выполнилась
4.3 В строке 12 script1 полученное в строке 4 значение(101) уменьшается на 10 и будет равно 91
4.4 В строке 10 script2 полученное в строке 4 значение(101) увеличивается на 10 и будет равно 111
4.5 Сохраняется значение 91 в строке 14 в скрипте script1
4.6 Сохраняется значение 111 в строке 14 в скрипте script2

Полученный в итоге результат равен 111, хотя после понижения на 10 в результате первого запроса, он должен был увеличиться на 5(как сказано в условии задачи). 101-10+5 = 96. Получаем конфликт данных из-за того, что мы проверили значение respect во время обработки второго запроса до того, как оно было изменено уже запущенным первым скриптом-обработчиком первого запроса.
Я постарался на простом примере описать реальную проблему, с которой столкнулся при разработке системы бронирования билетов на мероприятия. Буду рад любым рассуждениям и решениям

А не надо гонять данные через клиента. Ну да, получили, показали - чисто для справки. А при обновлении значения обновляем то, что лежит в таблице на момент обновления, а не то, что прочитали полчаса назад. И выводим новое значение. И если в результате интерференции юзер получил финально не то, на что рассчитывал - ну так это его проблемы, а не наши. Он как бы ничем не главнее того, кто параллельно с ним изменял значение.

@Akina проблема в том, что клиент не умеет в SQL :D Это очередная жертва добреньких дяденек, которые показали ему, как можно строгать сайты не зная SQL, с помощью волшебной библиотечки. И теперь, даже если объяснить ему, что все вычисления надо делать прямо в запросе, он все равно не сможет это реализовать

@Ипатьев Ну в принципе автор может обойтись и своим фреймворком, не используя сырого SQL... наверное - я не в курсе, что у него там за фреймворк и где у него границы сложности для запроса. Ему сейчас бы хотя бы понять чисто идеологически, что нет никаких оснований блокировать значение, прочитанное одним юзером, от изменения другим юзером, ибо с какой бы стати? А чтобы не нарываться на то, что итог не соответствует ожиданиям - ну так думать надо  быстрее, чтобы никто не влез.

@Akina ну тут еще такой момент, что он просто заврался, пытаясь зачем-то выдумать несуществующую задачу. Но в конце проговорился, что речь о бронировании билетов. То есть блокировка-то в реальности ему будет нужна. Но тут действительно - какой вопрос задал, на такой и ответ получил.

@Ипатьев Но в конце проговорился, что речь о бронировании билетов. То есть блокировка-то в реальности ему будет нужна. Ооо... а вот тут ба-а-альшой вопрос. Потому как это по факту получается бронирование бронирования, что по отношению к пользователям ну совсем не комильфо. Это я вошёл, заблокировал под себя сотню билетов, и закрыл браузер - а остальные сидят и сосут лапу, потому что свободных к раздаче билетов больше нет... и так, пока тайм-аут сессии не закончится... а я опять заблокирую, из другой сессии. Так можно весь сервис положить. Как раз "кто первый встал.." - честнее.

@Akina не-не, кто первый встал - это понятно. Но если он свои тапки получил, то другому их давать уже нельзя. А у автора классический код, который сначала проверяет, на месте ли тапки, а потом уже сует в них ноги. Вот он и спрашивает, как сделать, чтобы между проверкой и суванием никто тапки утащить не успел. И тут только два варианта: либо блокировать при проверке, либо ловить ошибку при бронировании. Но это если у тапок только булево состояние, есть или нету. А если какие-то сложные вычисления, то либо атомарный запрос со всеми вычислениями внутри, либо блокировка.

@Ипатьев блокировка реализована, здесь проблема в параллельности запросов к базе из двух процессов одного скрипта, работающих почти одновременно. Еще раз для всех уважаемых комментаторов -  речь идёт о МИЛИСЕКУНДАХ и небольшом шансе конфликтов. Не совсем понятно, зачем использовать тезисы по типу "заврался". Задача не несуществующая, а конкретная описанная на таком примере для простоты понимания.

Переформулирую вопрос. Как избежать параллельного выполнения нескольких копий конкретного php скрипта, ведь в теории даже между выполнением 2-х строк кода от проверки до внесения блокировки, другой процесс может выполнить проверку с ложным результатом. Соответственно обработка каждого запроса должна быть строго после  полного завершения предыдущей обработки этого типа запроса. Как это реализовать?

@Akina


Так можно весь сервис положить. Как раз "кто первый встал.." - честнее. Интересно)


А если пока один пользователь оплачивал выбранный билет и долго вводил номер карты к примеру, другой быстро выбрал тот же билет и оплатил его первым, получается что первый оплатит уже купленный другим пользователем билет и билета будет два продано на одно место)) Может на медленного пользователя и можно наплевать, но проблемы будут в такой ситуации у всей цепочки. К тому же блокировка может идти с ограничениями по времени и количеству, а совсем без нее - никуда.

Переформулирую вопрос. Как избежать параллельного выполнения нескольких копий конкретного php скрипта Это уже совсем другая задача. А если пока один пользователь оплачивал выбранный билет и долго вводил номер карты к примеру, другой быстро выбрал тот же билет и оплатил его первым, получается что первый оплатит уже купленный другим пользователем билет и билета будет два продано на одно место Это с какого перепугу-то? Продаётся не абстрактный, а вполне конкретный билет. И если первый его оплатил, то в таблице билетов появляется пометка. А запрос на оплату проверяет её отсутствие.

@Добровиктор ознакомьтесь с понятием блокировки в приложении к базам данных. А не перепродаже билетов.

@Akina у вас разговор слепого с глухим. Клиент не понимает, что такое блокировка в БД, хотя ему нужна именно она. И спрашивает он только про нее.А вы пытаетесь на пустом месте выдумать за него целиком систему резервирования, которая совершенно стандартная в бизнесе и никакого выдумывания не требует. И уже у него реализована. Плюс он при этом еще зачем-то выдумал задачу с вычислениями, про которые непонятно - то ли она за уши притянута, и решать её не надо, либо весь ответ внизу не имеет смысла, поскольку не учитывает эти шуры-муры "вчера большие, но по пять, а сегодня мелкие, но по три"

@Ипатьев Блокировка (SELECT .. FOR UPDATE) - конечно, штука стандартная. Но она ограничена соединением клиента с сервером БД. То есть на веб-сервере должен быть непрерывно работающий сервис, который держит это соединение от первого запроса юзера и до завершения оплаты либо отлупа по исчерпанию времени. И я фиг знает, есть у него такое или нет. Может, он вообще систему с нуля строит. Да, задача стандартная - но почему-то у автора в имеющихся средствах такая подсистема отсутствует.

@Akina я повторю ещё один раз, больше не буду. Клиента не интересует алгоритм продажи билетов. Я подозреваю, что про продажи он нам с вами и сам лекцию прочтет. И ни про какие блокировки на 15 минут речь тут не идет. Он для вас специально написал слово миллисекунды БОЛЬШИМИ БУКВАМИ. И повторил свой банальный вопрос ещё раз, теми же самыми словами: как избежать состояния гонки при обращении к одной и той же таблице в БД. И это не "совсем другая задача" а именно то, что его интересует. И решается, в одном из вариантов, блокировкой таблицы.
